# Pourquoi le subjonctif?

Tags: grammaire, usage, choix-de-mot

> Y a-t-il quelque chose en quoi je puisse vous être utile ?

Ne peut-on pas le remplacer par « peux » ?

Answer (score 1):

On peut.

Le subjonctif renforce l'incertitude de l'aide, le fait qu'elle soit sujette à un souhait.

> Y a-t-il quelque chose en quoi je **puisse** vous être utile ?

On rencontrera plus souvent le conditionnel qui indique une hypothèse :

> Y a-t-il quelque chose en quoi je **pourrais** vous être utile ?

ou l'une des deux formes du présent de l'indicatif :

> Y a-t-il quelque chose en quoi je **puis** vous être utile ?

> Y a-t-il quelque chose en quoi je **peux** vous être utile ?

Dans un interrogative simple, le plus courant sera :

> En quoi **puis-je** vous être utile ?

ou

> En quoi **pourrais-je** vous être utile ?

Le subjonctif est rarissime :

> En quoi **puissé-je** vous être utile?